# how to run line by line in text file - on windows mobile?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

in WinForm on PC i use to run like this:

```
FileStream FS = null;
StreamWriter SW = null;
FS = new FileStream(@"\Items.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);
SW = new StreamWriter(FS, Encoding.Default);
while (SW.Peek() != -1)
{
   TEMP = (SW.ReadLine());
}
```

but when i try this on Windows-mobile i get error:

```
Error   1   'System.IO.StreamWriter' does not contain a definition for 'Peek' and no extension method 'Peek' accepting a first argument of type 'System.IO.StreamWriter' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Error   2   'System.IO.StreamWriter' does not contain a definition for 'ReadLine' and no extension method 'ReadLine' accepting a first argument of type 'System.IO.StreamWriter' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

how to do it ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been mentioned, you're using a [streamwriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx) not a [streamreader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader(v=VS.90).aspx)

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("TestFile.txt")) 
            {
                string line;
                // Read and display lines from the file until the end of 
                // the file is reached.
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null) 
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(line);
                }
            }
```

Comment: @Gold Without knowing the format of the file I cant really help

Answer (score 4):

If you want to read something use a Reader not a Writer

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this?

```
using (var reader = File.OpenText("\\items.txt"))
{
    while(reader.Peek() > 0)
    {
        var line = reader.ReadLine();
        // do something with the line here
    }
}
```

I can't see how the code you have would work even on the desktop, since neither ReadLine nor Peek even exist on a [StreamWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter_methods%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Read all the data in a string. Then split the string using the \n and then read each value in a string array.

Comment: Its for a mobile device, thats the reason I thought about it.